# Best way to make hovering over one <a> element affect another?

Tags: html, css, hover

### Code:

My Code:

```
<a class="image_is_displayed_using_this"></a> - This is the image
<a class="text_with_it">Text here</a> - This is the text that should change color 
if above image is hovered.
```

If either of the two structures are hovered over, I want them to have the same color.  For the image, the image changes when it's hovered and the color of that image is red. I need the text to be red as well.

### Question:

How do I change the color of the text if the image is hovered?

### Edit:

The html document cannot be edited.

Comment: is it possible to wrap both `a` under the same container?

Comment: I can't.  The site's current stucture is in that way and nobody wants to change it.  Can't I do something with CSS3? I am googling stuff right now.

Comment: The colour of what text if what image is hovered? Show the *actual* HTML, don't describe it at us. Also, with reference to your question's title: *what `div` elements*?

Comment: it has to be pure CSS or you can use jQuery?

Comment: @agustinmeriles I am open to both but prefer less jquery.

Comment: Well - the additional detail changes your question somewhat significantly. As @david-thomas said - please show us the *actual* HTML, rather than describing it to us - or we can't give you a valid solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several approaches:

1. **IF** you have control over the HTML, and can add a wrapper element, you can put them both in a single containing element, and use CSS.

   ```
   <div class="hoverable">
     <a class="image_is_displayed_using_this"></a>
     <a class="text_with_it">Text here</a>
   </div>
   ```

   Then for CSS:

   ```
   .hoverable:hover > .text_with_it { color: red; }
   /* Or replace *red* with whatever color you want */
   ```

   This works by making the text change color based on the parent being hovered - which will be true when the mouse is over either the image `a` OR the text `a`.
2. **IF** your text `a` will always come immediately after your image `a`, and the only changes you need to make on-hover are changes to the `text`:

   ```
   <a class="image_is_displayed_using_this"></a>
   <a class="text_with_it">Text here</a>
   ```

   Then for CSS:

   ```
   .text_with_it:hover,
   .image_is_displayed_using_this:hover + .text_with_it { color: red; }
   ```

   This will make it so that whenever you mouse over the image OR the text, the text's color will change. Note that it is a bit more brittle, though - because it relies on your HTML being laid out in a specific manner.
3. Use an `IMG` tag - that's what they exist for.

   ```
   <a class="text_with_it">
     <img src="your_image_url.png" /> Text here
   </a>
   ```

   Then for CSS:

   ```
   a.text_with_it:hover { color: red; }
   ```
4. Lastly - if you need to do it with jQuery, try this:

   ```
   var selector = '.image_is_displayed_using_this, .text_with_it';
   $(selector).hover(function (ev) {
       $(this).siblings(selector).add(this).addClass('hovered');
   }).mouseout(function (ev) {
       $(this).siblings(selector).add(this).removeClass('hovered');
   });
   ```

   Then for CSS:

   ```
   a.hovered { color: red; }
   ```

   [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/dM4sF/) showing it working (very simplistic).

Comment: You can't nest interactive elements, such as `a`, or `button`, elements. Certainly Chromium [un-nests nested `a` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8MGB/).

Comment: Good point, @DavidThomas - I went ahead and removed that example, and added a jQuery version.

Comment: @troyalford thanks.  As a new guy learning this it's really helpful.  How can i do the same but reverse? Hover the text to change the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, @starbucks, that is one of those edge conditions. The `+` CSS selector works on elements immediately *pro*ceding an element. However, there is no pure-CSS way to target an element immediately *pre*ceding an element - which makes it tough. In that case, you may need to go to the jQuery solution - or - try to target the two elements' parent. I can help more with that if you update to the actual HTML.

Comment: Thanks @troyalford, what HTML changes would you recommend.  I will try and convince them to change it if it makes sense.

Comment: I can't suggest HTML changes until you actually show me what your HTML currently looks like. If you have the option, though, to make changes at all, try to alter your HTML to match my 1st solution above. That's the *right* way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap them both in an element like `<div class="hoverable"><a><img/></a><a>text</a></div>` then set the css `.hoverable:hover { color: yellow; }`

Comment: @starbucks said that can't modify the document

Comment: @AgustinMeriles Good catch. Javascript will have to do if he really can't edit the html portions. I recommended an edit of original question to make this more clear for others. Limitations like that are important to note.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS? to change the text red on hover

```
a :hover { color: # }
```

Should work when you hover over the image too, as they are both "a" elements

Comment: I'm not voting this down, because frankly there's no information in the question to enable any answers, but I suspect that the OP wants to hover over *one* element and affect another.

Answer (score 0):

based solely on your description, it's easiest in jquery:

```
$('a.image_is_displayed_using_this').hover( function() {
    $('a.text_with_it').css('background-color','gray');
}, function() {
    $('a.text_with_it').css('background-color','white');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.image_is_displayed_using_this").mouseout(function(){
        $("a.text_with_it").css("color", "black");
    }).mouseover(function(){
        $("a.text_with_it").css("color", "red");
    });
});
```